# Strange runtime behaviour of an update in a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, oracle11g

I have an old and a new table. In the old table, there is a `VARCHAR2` column, called `number`, with values like `11-38D402342` and `11-38D402342/43`. Also some crappy data, but never null.

In the new table, there are the two `VARCHAR2` columns `number_left` and `number_right`. these two were filled from the number column of the old table:

```
number_left  = nvl(substr(number,1,instr(number,'/',1)-1),number)
number_right = substr(number,1,instr(rtrim(number,'/'),'/',1)-length(substr(number,instr(number,'/'))))||substr(number,decode(instr(number,'/'),0,null,instr(number,'/')+1))
```

After some other decisions, we now need only one column again. To make sure the copied numbers get set correctly, I decided to use the number of the old table and the used conversion to identify matching rows.

I have a mapping but cannot use it since the number_left and number_right can be copied into new rows by an application and must get the old number too. So a number of the old table can possibly copied into multible rows in the new table.

I tried used this code:

```
declare
    left_num varchar2(255 char) := '';
    right_num varchar2(255 char) := '';
    pos number := 0;
    CURSOR c_number is
        select number from old_table;
begin
    for cur in c_number loop
        left_num := nvl(substr(cur.number,1,instr(cur.number,'/',1)-1),cur.number);
        if instr(cur.number,'/') = 0 then
          pos := null;
        else
          pos := instr(cur.number,'/')+1;
        end if;
        right_num := substr(cur.number,1,instr(rtrim(cur.number,'/'),'/',1)-length(substr(cur.number,instr(cur.number,'/'))))||substr(cur.number, pos);

        update new_table n
            set n.number = cur.snummer
            where n.number_left = left_num
            and (
              n.number_right = right_num
              or (
                n.number_right is null
                and right_num is null
              )
            );
    end loop;
end;
```

In the old table I have 170.000 lines and in the new one 180.000 since there is also some new data. Peanuts.

But here comes the strange part:
Everything seems to work fine but after the first 14.000 rows it gets terribly slow, perhaps 3 rows in a second. And I think it becomes slower and slower.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking a bunch of random starngers to take a guess you should learn how to trace the performance of SQL in the database.  There are several differnt ways you can gain insight into the performance of your statement, but you will ned some level of DBA-type access.

This is an area which is covered in [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/sqltrace.htm#i4170) but I suggest you start with Tim Hall's excellent overview.  [Find it here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof-10g.php).